# Different results for the same query but inside a function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a table with Pontuation(Pontuacao) and an unique number for Accomodation(Estadia) and i want to calculate the average pontuation of each accomodation.
This is the table:

```
Estadia | Pontuacao
-------------------
5       | 5
-------------------
5       | 5
```

So i made this funcion:

```
delimiter $$
create function mediapontuacao(estadia int)
returns float
begin
    declare media float;
    select sum(Pontuacao)/count(*) into media
        from EstadiaUtilizador
    where Estadia = estadia;
    return media;
end $$
```

If i do this

```
select mediapontuacao(5); //calculate average pontuation of the accomodation which number is 5
```

This query gives me the value of 3.965.
But if i do this

```
select sum(Pontuacao)/count(*)
      from EstadiaUtilizador
where Estadia = 5;
```

In other words calculate average pontuation of the accomodation which number is 5, the exact same thing the function i wrote should do and this query gives me the value of 5.00 which is the correct answer.
I am puzzled why i get different values when it should give the same value, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
where Estadia = estadia
```

which is the same as, say,

```
where 1 = 1
```

Your parameter and column should have different names, so the DBMS knows what you are talking about.

Comment: This was the problem, i thaught it was different. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `GROUP BY`clause

```
select
    Estadia,
    sum(Pontuacao) / count(*) as mediapontuacao
from
    EstadiaUtilizador
group by
    Estadia
having Estadia = 5
```